# How can I install unixODBC without brew?

Tags: python-3.x, macos, pip, pyodbc, unixodbc

I am trying to use the pyodbc package in Python 3.6, but get an image error. Upon researching, some have suggested that Macs require a unixODBC package to fix the error. I don’t have access to use brew. Is it possible to install unixODBC with pip or similar method?

So far, I’ve tried using pip3 install unixodbc and pip3 install with the url of the tar.gz file on the unixodbc site. Any ideas?